# css fixed header fixed sections

Tags: html, css

I give the header fixed property, but the independent section is affected by it.

```css
header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px 40px ;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
 <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo">logo</a>
        <ul>
            <li>sdsdsd</li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    
    <section>
        adsdsadsdf
    </section>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a very common problem with positioning the headers or navbars on a website.

The problem is that the `position: fixed` property puts the element out of the document flow and anything under it gets pulled behind the element.

One way to solve this problem would be to add `margin-top` property to the section underneath the header. This will bring down the section.

Other way (recommended way) would be to add `position: sticky` to the header instead of `position: fixed`. This will for the most part work the same as `position: fixed` but it will not pop out the element from the document flow.

The final code would look like:

```css
header{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px 40px ;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
  <ul>
    <li>List Item</li>
  </ul>
</header>
    
<section>
  Section Area
</section>
```

There is a great article by Kevin Powell on this topic if you wanna check it out - https://www.kevinpowell.co/article/positition-fixed-vs-sticky/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't want to use sticky feature or fix it with margin. It makes me have to give margin-top to every section I create. It's ridiculous. There must be another way.

Comment: @lparalyzed You wouldn't need to add margin-top on every section you create. Adding it  to only the first section will get the job done. It will move all the sections created below along with itself, as those section are not taken out of the document flow.